# MongoDB Query, sort then take nth document for group

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to compose a [MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) query...

My aim is to retrieve a list of player records by `country` sorted by `rating` and then return **only** the nth rated player for each country (so the top rated, or the 3rd best rated etc).

I have achieved part I:

```
db.getCollection('players').find( { event: 'open' }).sort({ country: 1, rating: -1 });
```

#### Update

Here is sample of two countries with three players for each, ordered by rating:

**Team One:**

```
{
    "id" : 400041,
    "name" : "Adams Michael",
    "rating" : 2727,
    "country" : "England",
    "event" : "open"
},
{
    "id" : 404853,
    "name" : "McShane Luke J",
    "rating" : 2671,
    "country" : "England",
    "event" : "open",
},
{
    "id" : 400025,
    "name" : "Short Nigel D",
    "rating" : 2666,
    "country" : "England",
    "event" : "open"
}
```

**Team Two:**

```
 {
    "id": 4101588,
    "name": "Kramnik Vladimir",
    "rating": 2808,
    "country": "Russia",
    "event": "open"
},
{
    "id": 4126025,
    "name": "Grischuk Alexander",
    "rating": 2784,
    "country": "Russia",
    "event": "open"
},
{
    "id": 14109603,
    "name": "Karjakin Sergey",
    "rating": 2769,
    "country": "Russia",
    "event": "open"
}
```

I want my query to return the objects for:

- Adams Michael
- Kramnik Vladimir

(as these are the two highest rated)

I want my query to also allow me to query for the second highest rated:

- McShane Luke J
- Grischuk Alexander

Comment: add `limit` at the end of sort like `.sort({"rating":-1,"country":1}).limit(1)`

Comment: @Yogesh how would that work if I wanted to retrieve the 3rd rated player (and only the 3rd rated players of all countries)?

Comment: for that case you should use https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.skip/ skip something like this `.limit(1).skip(2)`

Comment: @Yogesh `.limit(1)` returns only one record total, not 1 record for each country.

Comment: It's better way you should edit your question what exactly you want and as per your comment it's looks like you should use `aggregation`

Comment: @MattWebb as Yogesh has mentioned this is solvable using aggregation as outlined below, cheers

Comment: @Philar cool, that's awesome. I will check this out.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is how you would do it using a 4 stage aggregation pipeline

1. Sort country-wise and rating-wise as you have done already
2. Group by country and push all player details into an array
3. This one is the clincher. Use `project` with `$arrayElemAt`to get the `ith` rated player for each of the respective countries
4. Use project again to give you the object in the desired format

   ```
   db.getCollection('players').aggregate(
   {
       $sort: {country: 1, rating: -1}
   },
   {
       $group:   {
           _id: "$country", 
           players: {$push: {name: "$name", rating: "$rating", event: "$event"}}
       }
   },
   {
       $project: {
           player: {$arrayElemAt: ["$players", iTH_RATING]}
       } 
   },
   {
       $project: {
           name: "$player.name",
           rating: "$player.rating",
           event: "$player.event"
           }
   })
   ```

See screen grab below for `2nd Highest Rated Players`. Since these are `0-indexed`, the `iTH_RATING` variable in the query is replaced with 1. To get the highest rated players replace with 0, so on and so forth.
[image: 2nd Highest Rated Players]

Comment: Nice! indeed this should be the best solution. Need to read the manual again, MongoDB 3 brought a lot of new features :P  I suggest to remove the `country:1` from the projection cause is useles, the `_id` stores the country value

Answer (score 1):

You can achive that using multiple queries, one for each country, using `$skip` and `$limit` as Yogesh says in his comments.

You can use map-reduce, than you will get the expected result in 1 'query' (but bear in mind that map-reduce is not suitable for real-time queries, maybe be very slow operation but that strongly depends on your data size).

In the map function, fire documents with the key as country. In the reduce function, sort your players from the same country based on rating, and return only the document (player) from the desired position in the ranking:

```
var map = function map(){
    emit(this.country, this);

};

var reduce = function(key, values){
    var position_to_return = 1; // change here to 0 to return the first rated player for certain country
    var sorted_values = values.sort(function(first, second) {
        return second.rating - first.rating;
    })
    return key, sorted_values[position_to_return];
};


db.runCommand({"mapReduce":"players", map:map, reduce:reduce, out:{replace:"players2"}, query:{ "event": "open" }})
```

output, when returning second rated players for each country:

```
{
    "_id" : "England",
    "value" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("57bb093c6124c1a9d8be905d"),
        "id" : 404853,
        "name" : "McShane Luke J",
        "rating" : 2671,
        "country" : "England",
        "event" : "open"
    }
}
{
    "_id" : "Russia",
    "value" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("57bb093c6124c1a9d8be9060"),
        "id" : 4126025,
        "name" : "Grischuk Alexander",
        "rating" : 2784,
        "country" : "Russia",
        "event" : "open"
    }
}
```

Comment: Sergiu, using the the `$sort` and `$arrayElemAt` combination can get you the results using aggregation. Do look at the solution i have suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with aggregation.  If you **$sort** before your **$group** stage, you can use **$first** to retrieve data from the first relevant document for each group (country):

```
db.getCollection('players').aggregate([
    {
        $sort: { country: 1, rating: -1 }
    },
    {
        $group:{
            _id: "$country",
            "highest_rated": { "$first": "$name" }
        }
    }
]);
```

If you want all attribution from the matching document (not just player name) you can use $$ROOT:

```
db.getCollection('players').aggregate([
    {
        $sort: { country: 1, rating: -1 }
    },
    {
        $group:{
            _id: "$country",
            "highest_rated": { "$first": "$$ROOT" }
        }
    }
]);
```

Comment: This is almost what I need, I have updated my question to explain it a little better.

If I want to return the second or third highest rated, how would I do so using `$group`.

Comment: With the change to the question, seeking the nth ranked document as opposed to the first, this isn't something you can do with a simple query.