# How to know number of position document in MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb

What is the best way to look for a document’s position in a collection?

Using the following code. But its works so bad with my big collection of documents.

```
get_top_func(user_score):
   return len(db.collection.find({'score': {'$gt': user_score}})) + 1
```

Comment: Are you sure your question is worded properly in the title? The title and the query you gave as example do two different things: Asking for a position ≠ getting the first item with a value greater than *x*

Comment: Sorry, i forgot add some of my code. Full code is:
len(db.collection.find_one({'score': {'$gt': 24125}}))+1

Comment: It would be better to edit the question rather than add it to a comment. It will be more readable.

Comment: ... wait ... with your last comment, this still does not seem to be the same thing. Can you extend your question a bit and add example data and code (even if it is pseudocode). An [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be even better. If you show the output you currently get and the output that you *want* to get it will be much easier to formulate an answer.

Comment: Gived example of my func

Comment: I appreciate the example, but it's still really not clear what you are asking. I would love to help, but I don't understand the problem. Can you add an example data-set (with just a few records) and the expected output? That's always a good practice when asking questions like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a field like `myDocId` as the key and value to be like a variable that functions as a counter.

So while inserting each document in a collection, you'll be having its number also stored with the document data as well.

Each document in a collection has an identifier key that is stuffed my mongoDB itself which is `_id` but that wont tell you exactly which number of document is it(like nth document) as its made up using 4 parameters

- a 4-byte value representing the seconds since the Unix epoch,
- a 3-byte machine identifier,
- a 2-byte process id, and
- a 3-byte counter, starting with a random value.

Also refer https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/

and also [MongoDB Query, sort then take nth document for group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39079496/mongodb-query-sort-then-take-nth-document-for-group)

So what you can do is using aggregate you can use your filters and then project as needed to get the nth element using the $arrayElemAt.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/

Comment: This is good idea, but I have one problem, this is not just providing the doc_id to the document, but these are the top users. For example, to solve the problem of the problem that I didn’t explain well: if you want to get doc_id in order, create a global document that has a counter with your doc_id! But this is another thing, unlike what I want ...

Comment: you can see this aggregate from mongodb https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/ and also refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39079496/mongodb-query-sort-then-take-nth-document-for-group.

Answer (score 0):

Considering your query and the fact that you mention that the query is slow, I am guessing that you don't have an index on the `score` field. [Creating and index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/) should make this query faster:

```
db.collection.createIndex( { score: -1 } )
```

After that, you should be able to run the query you have with better performance.

Comment: How can this be conveniently used to get the top users, I apologize for not adding the code :)

Comment: I have trouble understanding your question. The title says that you are looking for a position of a record, the questions shows code which looks at any record having a score larger than 24125, and now you ask for getting the "top users" which are all 3 completely different use-cases with different queries. You should clarify your question. Otherwise it will be very hard to give a good answer.